# Understanding SIGCHLD when the child process terminates

Tags: c, linux

I am not able to understand the output for the following program. I observed that after the child process returns, parent process is not sleeping for 3 sec before wait(). If SIGCHLD is set to default handler, then it sleeping for 3 sec, calling wait and returning as expected. What is exactly happening here ??

```
# include <unistd.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <sys/wait.h>
# include <signal.h>

void handler(int sig) {
printf("Iam in handler ...\n");
}

main() {

int status;
pid_t pid;

struct sigaction act;
//act.sa_flags=SA_NOCLDSTOP;
act.sa_handler=handler;
sigaction(SIGCHLD,&act,NULL);

if(!fork()) {
printf("child process id is  %d\n",getpid());
 return 1;
}  

printf("xxx ...\n");
sleep(3);
pid = wait(&status);
printf("process terminated is %d\n",pid);

}

output::

xxx ...
child process id is  2445
Iam in handler ...
process terminated is 2445
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the child process dies a `SIGCHLD` is sent to the parent. In your case it interrupts the `sleep` and it looks as if the process doesn't sleep.

The gist of the issue: `sleep` isn't restarted when interrupted by a signal.

Comment: thanks for ur answer. One more doubt - i have read from posts that restarting of the system calls is upto the its implementation defined and some of the system calls do not restart at all.Is it true ? Does restarting of system calls is same as calling the same call twice ??

Comment: @Goutham it's not the same. Think of it as "a signal that tries not to return `EINTR`. And yes, signal restarting is mostly implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 13):

From the [man for sleep()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep):

> sleep() makes the calling thread sleep until *seconds* seconds have elapsed or a signal arrives which is not ignored.

Your child terminating causes a signal to wake you up.

The return value from `sleep()`:

> Zero if the requested time has elapsed, or the number of seconds left to sleep, if the call was interrupted by a signal handler.

Can be used if you'd like to help you "finish" the sleep.

```
unsigned sleep_time = 3;
...
while((sleep_time = sleep(sleep_time)) > 0) {}
pid = wait(&status);
...
```