# What does signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_DFL); mean?

Tags: linux, signals, posix, zombie-process, waitpid

I am not handling `SIGCHLD` in my code. Still my process is removed immediately after termination. I want it to become zombie process.

If I set `SIGCHLD` to `SIG_DFL` then, will it work? How do I set `SIGCHLD` to `SIG_DFL`?

I want process to become zombie, so I can read the child status in parent after `waitpid`.

Comment: You should *always* read the child status with `waitpid` notably when you have installed a `SIGCHLD` handler (or without it). Read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), [signal(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html), [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) for details.

Comment: waitpid returns -1 with errno = ECHILD. So child status is not valid and some garbage only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From your question history you seem to be tying yourself in knots over this.  Here is the outline on how this works:

1. The default disposition of SIGCHLD is ignore.  In other words, if you do nothing, the *signal* is ignored but the zombie exists in the process table.  This why you can `wait` on it at any time after the child dies.
2. If you set up a signal handler then the signal is delivered and you can reap it as appropriate but the (former) child is still a zombie between the time it dies and the time you reap it.
3. If you *manually* set SIGCHLD's disposition to SIG_IGN via `signal` then the semantics are a little different than they are in item 1.  When you manually set this disposition the OS immediately removes the child from the process table when it dies and does *not* create a zombie.  Consequently there is no longer any status information to reap and `wait` will fail with ECHILD.  (Linux kernels after 2.6.9 adhere to this behavior.)

Answer (score 0):

So your final target is to read return code in parent process after your child process exit? I don't see this has any matter with signal. Some example code is:

```
short pid;
if((pid == fork()) == 0) {
// Child process do some thing here.
exit(n);
} else {
  int returnCode;
  while(pid != wait(&returnCode));
  // the child has terminated with returnCode
  // wait is blocking system call so u don't need to worry about busy waiting.
}
```

Comment: Yes, here I am always getting -1 (return value) from wait. I am expecting to get child pid as return value from wait. So I can proceed with child status. Which is not happening in my case.. When I check errno it is ECHILD. So How to check SIGCHLD flag?

Comment: see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266485/understanding-sigchld-when-the-child-process-terminates) bounds the signal with a handler, see what's going on.