# How to create a waiting process (worker) with fork?

Tags: c

I don't know if I'm asking the right question, but after several hours of searching, I can't find my answer. So I explain what I need.

I would like to create a `child process` with `fork` and that child process will wait until it receives a signal or changes a variable value. I mean I don't want to be creating a process every time I need it, I want it to wait and run when I tell it to, as many times as it needs to.

I have tried several things, but they have not worked, I put the code, I really do not know what to look for to do what I need without thread, or is it only possible to do it with `thread`?

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t runChild = 0;


static void handler(int signum, siginfo_t *sinfo, void *unused){

    if (signum == SIGUSR1) {
        printf("SIGUSR1 received\n");
        runChild = 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *newArgv[] = {"myecho", "hello", "world", NULL};
    char *newEnviron[] = { "MY_NAME=jcarlosweb", NULL };

    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_flags =0;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);

    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
        while (!runChild) {
            usleep(200);
        }
        runChild = 0;
        execve("./process-pipe-fork/execve/myecho", newArgv, newEnviron);
        /* The execve function returns only if an error occurs. */
        perror("An error occurred in execve");
        abort();
    }
    
    // continue execution of parent process without waiting for child process to finish
    waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG);

    printf("Run myecho:\n");
    kill(pid,SIGUSR1);

    sleep(3);

    printf("Run myecho:\n");
    kill(pid,SIGUSR1);

    printf("Done\n");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The `execve` of my `myecho` program only runs once, and I would like to run it when I say so throughout the main program.

In this case I'm using the `exec` in the child process, but I could have just put a function that prints a message, for example. The idea I am looking for is the same

Comment: Unrelated to your main question, but `waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG);`  effectively does nothing at all.  It would be used to test whether the child has already exited, immediately returning 0 if yes and -1 if no, but you ignore the return value.  You don't need any system call for the parent and child to run independently; that's what happens by default when you fork.  You call `waitpid` or one of its relatives when you want the parent to *wait* instead of going on running.  I think you may have misunderstood something in the documentation.

Comment: You should be calling `waitpid`, *without* `WNOHANG`, at the *end* of the parent process, so that it reaps the child before exiting, and doesn't leave it around to pollute your shell session with its output.  If you really want the child to go on running after the parent exits and returns you to a shell, you are writing a *daemon* and some extra steps are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Block on a pipe. This might look something like...

```
#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void) {
    char ch;
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    ssize_t ret;

    pipe(fd); /* to block on */

    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        err(1, "fork failed");
    } else if (pid == 0) { /* child */
        close(fd[1]);
        warnx("child  %d start", getpid());
        /* block until parent goes away */
        ret = read(fd[0], &ch, 1);
        warnx("child  %d is go", getpid());
        close(fd[0]);
        /* child now does things here ... */
    } else { /* parent */
        sleep(3);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        /* parent does more things here ... */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. At what point do I notify the child process that it has to run, by sending `write` to `fd[1]`, I'm going to try if I can do it as many times as I want to activate the child.

Comment: The child is notified (unblocked would be a better word) when the parent calls `close` on a suitable portion of the pipe. You could also keep the pipes open and write something to a suitable pipe (the parent really should close one of the pipes, in that case) to unblock the child.

Comment: I try to write directly from the main program part and it doesn't work, I put two write one separated by sleep, only the first one is written, the second one doesn't do anything, so I think this is not the way, I think I'm quite confused with the use of fork, I thought it could be waiting in the background and "unlock" it in any part of the main program, as many times as I need.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot wait on a child *process* for a variable change because the parent process and the child are different processes, and so, they have each their own virtual address space (with no intersections)

There are several ways to do what you want.  One has been suggested in another answer, so I will not extend on it, as it looks fine to me.

- You can create a thread.  A thread runs in a separate stack (separate from main thread) but the whole virtual address space is the same.  Both running threads (main and the one you create) share the same addresses and so, one can modify a variable and the other can be looking at it for a change.  This solution is feasible, but not very efficient, as while the waiting process is waiting for the variable to change (the variable needs to be defined as `volatile`, so the compiler doesn't cache the value anywhere and the true value is the one the other thread stores in it) it is consuming cpu making your resources wasted for no reason.
- You can use (in a different process) a semaphore, (`man semop`) for the parent process to change it.
- You can use shared memory between processes (see `man shmop` or `man mmap`) and so, only the memory corresopnding to the shared memory segment is shared between both processes.
- You can use a socket.  A socket is a bidirectional communication channel between parent and child, and so it allows you to use a complex protocol to do the most variable communication messages between both processes.  You can use reliable unix sockets for this (they are fast, reliable, but require both processes to be in the same machine)  or network sockets (the API is the same, which gives you a versatile approach that you can later change in case your needs change)

I recommend you to read:

- `pthread_create(3)` and similar manual pages.  A reference of threads.
- `pthread_mutex(3)` and similar manual pages. A reference to synchronization between threads.
- `semop(2)`  and friends.  Reference to sysv5 semaphores.
- `mmap(2)` and friends.  Reference to shared memory segments.
- `pipe(2)` and fifo related documentation.  This will show you how a pipe can be used, as it blocks readers and writers when the internal buffer it has is full/empty.  This can be a good starting point.

The following code `fork()`s a child and then it feeds its child with all its own input, while the parent is writing to standard output its own input, it also feeds to the child its input, so the child will work on it and write to a file `output.txt`:
###pru.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd[2];

    /* we need to get the pipe before fork() so we have it in both,
     * parent and child. */
    int res = pipe(fd);
    if (res < 0) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    int child_pid = fork();

    if (child_pid < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* both processes get here. */
    if (child_pid == 0) { /* we are the child only */
        close(fd[1]); /* we are not using the writing end */
        FILE *out = fopen("output.txt", "a+");
        FILE *f   = fdopen(fd[0], "r");
        int   c;
        while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
            /* print an hex representation of char */
            fprintf(out, "<%02x>", c);
        }
        /* let's close both */
        fclose(out); fclose(f);
        /* remember the child gets 0 from fork, so it needs to
         * call getpid() syscall to get its pid. */
        printf("Child (pid=%d) exiting.\n", getpid());
        exit(0);
        /* NOTREACHED */
    } else {
        close(fd[0]); /* we don't use the reading end */
        /* we are writing on the writing side of the pipe */
        FILE *out = fdopen(fd[1], "w");
        int c;
        while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
            /* make a copy for the child */
            fputc(c, out);
            /* and write to stdout */
            fputc(c, stdout);
        }
        fclose(out); /* signal the child that there's no more output */
        fprintf(stderr,
                "Waiting for the child (whose pid should be %d)"
                " to finish\n",
                child_pid);
        int status;
        pid_t exited_pid = wait(&status);
        if (exited_pid < 0) {
            perror("wait");
            exit(1);
        }
        fprintf(stderr,
            "%d exited with status %d\n",
            exited_pid, status);
        exit(0);
        /* NOTREACHED */
    } /* else */
} /* main */
```

whose output is:

```
$ echo "Hello, world" | ./a.out
Hello, world
Waiting for the child (whose pid should be 2833) to finish
Child (pid=2833) exiting.
2833 exited with status 0
$ _
```

and the contents of `output.txt`:

```
$ cat output.txt
<48><65><6c><6c><6f><2c><20><77><6f><72><6c><64><0a>$ _
```

Comment: "You cannot wait on a child process for a variable change": But the original program's not actually trying to share a variable between parent and child, is it?  The parent sends a signal to the child.  The child's signal handler sets the *child's* copy of `runChild`, which is supposed to cause the child to end its `usleep` loop.  In principle that should work.

Comment: And it *does* work, the first time.  The problem is just that `execve` doesn't return and so the child process is no longer alive when the parent tries to signal it the second time.  I wrote an answer for OP.

Comment: if you want to wait for a signal to come, there's a system call for that (`pause(2)`) and you don't need to set an alarm, as it happens with `usleep(3)`

Comment: `execve` never returns.  it just loads the specified program on the current process, making it to execute another program, but there's no process creation in `execve`.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer has also helped me and I have just published 3 examples of what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your complaint is that `myecho` runs after the first `kill(pid, SIGUSR1)` but not the second time?  But as you said yourself, `execve` doesn't return if it succeeds!

Upon successful `execve` the child process is no longer running your program at all, it's running the `myecho` program, which doesn't handle signals, and when `myecho` calls `_exit()` the process exits.    So by the time the parent calls `kill(pid, SIGUSR1)` the second time, your child process is a [zombie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process).  The second `kill` won't fail, but it also won't have any effect; a zombie can't respond to signals.

If you want the child to stick around and keep responding to signals, then the child cannot call `execve` itself to run `myecho`.  Instead, each time the signal is received, the child must fork *again*, creating a grandchild process to do the `exec`.  The original child doesn't call `execve` but just returns to its sleep loop to wait for another signal.

As a side remark, I think you've misunderstood the role of `waitpid`.  Your  `waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG);` effectively does nothing at all. It would be used to test whether the child had already exited and reap it if so, immediately returning 0 if yes and -1 if no, but you ignore the return value. You don't need any system call for the parent and child to run independently; that's what happens by default when you fork. You call `waitpid` or one of its relatives when you want the parent to wait instead of going on running. I think you may have misunderstood something in the documentation.

Which raises the question of who *is* going to clean up all those zombies.  They will stay around and pollute the process table until their parent calls `waitpid`.  You could have the child process, on every wakeup, call `waitpid(WNOHANG)` in a loop until it returns -1 to reap all grandchildren that have exited.  Or you could use a `SIGCHLD` handler.  Likewise, the parent should really be arranging somehow for the child to terminate before the parent does (kill it with another signal, for instance), and then the parent should `waitpid` for the child, *without* `WNOHANG`, before it itself exits.

Finally, instead of `usleep` in a loop, the preferred way to wait for a signal is with `sigwait()`.  In that case you don't actually need the `runChild` flag.  You still have to install a signal handler for `SIGUSR1` but it can just do nothing.

I can try to come back later and post a fixed version of your program as an example.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has cleared up many doubts, and I think about `waitpid` too, I thought it was obligatory to use `waitpid`, even if I didn't want to wait for any child to terminate, but now I see that what I do is just to see if any child has finished at the execution point where it is running...

Comment: I will remove `waitpid` for now, and I will do several tests and come back, I will pass you the code and that way you can make your example with my idea and your explanation and give your answer as correct. The other answer is very good, but it didn't clear so many doubts, and it's true that I can use thread, but my goal in this question was not threads, that example I want to do it later.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answers of Nate Eldredge and Luis Colorado I have been able to create 3 examples. I'm going to post them in case it helps other people, I've really done this as an exercise to learn C, but these the examples are nothing without the help of Nate Eldredge and Luis Colorado. I also did another example with sigwait, but I've seen that with Semaphore it's simpler.

**1 - Posix Semaphore:**

```
struct sigaction sa; // signal
short int *runChildProcess; // mmap shared memory   
sem_t *sem; // semaphore

static void handleChildTerm(int signum, siginfo_t *sinfo, void *unused) {
    printf("Child %d exited\n", (int)sinfo->si_pid);
}

static void runChild(pid_t pid) {
    if (sem_post(sem) == -1) {
        perror("sem_post run child");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // When SIGCHLD is caught, sleep(3) is interrupted
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266485/understanding-sigchld-when-the-child-process-terminates
    unsigned short int sleepTime = 3;
    while ((sleepTime = sleep(sleepTime)) > 0)
        ;
}

static void termChild(pid_t pid) {
    *runChildProcess = 0; // set to 0 to exit the loop
    runChild(pid);
    if(munmap(runChildProcess, sizeof *runChildProcess) == -1) {
        perror("Munmap");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (sem_destroy(sem) == -1) {
        perror("sem_destroy");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    setbuf(stdout, NULL); // make stdout unbuffered

    // mmap: memory mapping file, shared with child process with the flag MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED
    runChildProcess = mmap(NULL, sizeof *runChildProcess, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
    if (runChildProcess == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    *runChildProcess = 1;

    // semaphore
    sem = mmap(0, sizeof(*sem), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    if (sem_init(sem, 1 /*shared*/, 0 /*init val*/) == -1) {
        perror("sem_init");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // signal handler for SIGCHLD (exit child process)
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART | SA_NOCLDWAIT;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_sigaction = handleChildTerm;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction SIGCHLD");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (pid == 0) { // child process
        while (*runChildProcess) {
            sem_wait(sem);
            if (*runChildProcess == 0) {
                break;
            }
            printf("Child process started: %d\n", getpid());
        }
        _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    printf("Parent process: %d\n", getpid());

    runChild(pid);
    runChild(pid);
    runChild(pid);

    termChild(pid);

    printf("Done\n");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**2 - Pipes**

```
#include <errno.h>     // for errno
#include <signal.h>    // sigaction
#include <stdbool.h>   // bool
#include <stdio.h>     // printf
#include <stdlib.h>    // exit
#include <string.h>    // strlen
#include <sys/mman.h>  // mmap
#include <sys/types.h> // pid_t
#include <unistd.h>    // fork

bool *runChildProcess; // mmap shared memory

int fd[2]; // pipe

static void runTermChildHandler(int signum, siginfo_t *sinfo, void *unused) {
    *runChildProcess = 0;
}
static void termChildHandler(int signum, siginfo_t *sinfo, void *unused) {
    printf("Child %d exited\n", (int)sinfo->si_pid);
}

static void runChild(int pipeFd, char *buffer) {

    if (write(pipeFd, buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1) == -1) {
        perror("write");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // When SIGCHLD is caught, sleep(3) is interrupted
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266485/understanding-sigchld-when-the-child-process-terminates
    unsigned short int sleepTime = 3;
    while ((sleepTime = sleep(sleepTime)) > 0)
        ;
}

static void termChild(pid_t pid, int pipeFd) {

    kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
    close(pipeFd);
    unsigned short int sleepTime = 1;
    while ((sleepTime = sleep(sleepTime)) > 0);

    munmap(runChildProcess, sizeof *runChildProcess);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    setbuf(stdout, NULL); // make stdout unbuffered

    // mmap: memory mapping file, shared with child process with the flag MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED
    runChildProcess = mmap(NULL, sizeof *runChildProcess, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
    if (runChildProcess == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    *runChildProcess = 1; // set to 1 to run the loop

    struct sigaction sa;

    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sa.sa_sigaction = runTermChildHandler;
    if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction SIGUSR1");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_SIGINFO | SA_NOCLDSTOP;
    sa.sa_sigaction = termChildHandler;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction SIGCHLD");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char buffer[100];

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
        close(fd[1]); // close write end of pipe
        printf("Child process: %d\n", getpid());
        while (*runChildProcess) {
            ssize_t nbytes = read(fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer)); // block until data is available from parent process
            if (nbytes == -1) {                 // EINTR: interrupted by a signal, although SA_RESTART is set no is no need to check for EINTR
                if (errno == EINTR) { 
                   continue;
                }else{
                    perror("read");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }
            if (nbytes == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            printf("Buffer: %s\n", buffer);
        }
        close(fd[0]); // close read end of pipe
        _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    printf("Parent process: %d\n", getpid());
    close(fd[0]); // close read end of pipe

    runChild(fd[1], "Thanks Nate Eldredge");
    runChild(fd[1], "Thanks Luis Colorado");
    runChild(fd[1], "Thanks www.stackoverflow.com");
    termChild(pid, fd[1]);

    printf("Done\n");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**3 - Semaphore with execve**

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 

struct sigaction sa; // signal

short int *runChildProcess; // mmap shared memory

sem_t *sem; // semaphore

static void handleChildTerm(int signum, siginfo_t *sinfo, void *unused) {
    printf("Child %d exited\n", (int)sinfo->si_pid);
}

static void runChild(pid_t pid) {
    if (sem_post(sem) == -1) {
        perror("sem_post");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // When SIGCHLD is caught, sleep(3) is interrupted
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266485/understanding-sigchld-when-the-child-process-terminates
    unsigned short int sleepTime = 3;
    while ((sleepTime = sleep(sleepTime)) > 0)
        ;
}

static void termChild(pid_t pid) {
    *runChildProcess = 0; // set to 0 to exit the loop
    runChild(pid);
    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_DFL);  // restore default signal handler
    if(munmap(runChildProcess, sizeof *runChildProcess) == -1) {
        perror("Munmap");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (sem_destroy(sem) == -1) {
        perror("sem_destroy");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    setbuf(stdout, NULL); // make stdout unbuffered

    // mmap: memory mapping file, shared with child process with the flag MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED
    runChildProcess = mmap(NULL, sizeof *runChildProcess, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
    if (runChildProcess == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    *runChildProcess = 1;

    // semaphore
    sem = mmap(0, sizeof(*sem), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    if (sem_init(sem, 1 /*shared*/, 0 /*init val*/) == -1) {
        perror("sem_init");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // signal handler for SIGCHLD (exit child process)
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART | SA_NOCLDWAIT;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_sigaction = handleChildTerm;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction SIGCHLD");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (pid == 0) { // child process
        char rootChildPidParam[10];
        snprintf(rootChildPidParam, 10, "%d", getpid());

        char *childArgv[] = {"process-pipe-fork/execve/myecho", "hello", "world", rootChildPidParam, NULL};
        char *childEnviron[] = {"MY_NAME=jcarlosweb", NULL};
        printf("Root Child started: %s\n", rootChildPidParam);

        while (*runChildProcess) {
            sem_wait(sem);
            // check again
            if (*runChildProcess == 0) {
                break;
            }
            pid_t leafChildPid = fork();
            if (leafChildPid == -1) {
                perror("fork sibling");
                _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if (leafChildPid == 0) { // child process
                printf("Leaf process with execve started: %d\n", getpid());
                // TODO: make child process in background
                execve("process-pipe-fork/execve/myecho", childArgv, childEnviron);
                perror("execve myecho");
                _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
           
        }
        _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    printf("Parent process: %d\n", getpid());

    runChild(pid);
    runChild(pid);
    runChild(pid);
    
    termChild(pid);

    printf("Done\n");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```